# Angular service wire up not working

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service

I have written a service, depending on an other service. But initialisation is not working.

[You can find a plunker as showcase](http://plnkr.co/edit/3d87fU9lZFfApSkr8TTb)

Should be close to working... Any tipps?
Thanks in advance!

edit: The plunker is fixed now and can be used as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either change your `testServiceMockConfig` and `testService` from `factory` to `service`, for example:

```
.service('testServiceMockConfig', function ()
```

or keep them as factories and add `return.this;` at the bottom of both of them or restructure them like this (recommended):

```
angular.module('testServiceMockConfig', [])
  .factory('testServiceMockConfig', function() {
    console.log("setup cqrs mock config.");

    return {
      doLoadItems: function(callback) {
        console.log("mock loading data");
        if (!this.configuredLoadItems) {
          throw Error("The mock is not configured to loadItems().");
        }
        callback(this.loadItemsError, this.loadItemsSuccess);
      },
      whenLoadItems: function(success, error) {
        this.configuredLoadItems = true;
        this.loadItemsSuccess = success;
        this.loadItemsError = error;
      }
    };
  });
```

I also assume that `loadItems` in `testService` should call:

```
testServiceMockConfig.doLoadItems(callback);
```

instead of:

```
testService.doLoadItems(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks. After struggling around with service, factory ... setup, you get blind for the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

As I see from your example,

- you didn't define properly the `factory.` The `this` key used for `service`
- in  `testService.doLoadItems(callback);` replace with `testServiceMockConfig.doLoadItems(callback);`

The difference between **service** - **factory** - **provider** and definition you can find in this simple demo:

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/PxdSP/14/)</kbd>

*Fixed example:*

```
angular.module('testServiceMockConfig', [])
    .factory('testServiceMockConfig', function () {
        console.log("setup cqrs mock config.");

        return{
        doLoadItems : function (callback) {
            console.log("mock loading data");
            if (!this.configuredLoadItems) {
                throw Error("The mock is not configured to loadItems().");
            }
            callback(this.loadItemsError, this.loadItemsSuccess);
        },
        whenLoadItems : function (success, error) {
            this.configuredLoadItems = true;
            this.loadItemsSuccess = success;
            this.loadItemsError = error;
        }
        }
    });


angular.module('testService', ['testServiceMockConfig'])
    .factory('testService', ['testServiceMockConfig', function (testServiceMockConfig) {

        console.log("mock version. testServiceMockConfig: ");

        return {
          loadItems : function (callback) {
            testServiceMockConfig.doLoadItems(callback);
        }
        }
    }])


angular.module('ItemApp', ['testService'])
    .controller('ItemsCtrl', ['$scope', 'testService', function ($scope, testService) {
        $scope.text = 'No items loaded';
        testService.loadItems(function (error, items) {
            if (error) {
                $scope.text = "Error happened";
            }
            $scope.text = '';
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                $scope.text = $scope.text + items[i].name;
            }
        })
    }]);
```

Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xf0zyj2ZOhCiDndbfF08?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. After struggling around with service, factory ... setup, you get blind for the obvious.